# Reading a CSV file and inserting it in a DB using both Spring Integration and Batch

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

[image][image]I have an application that monitors FTP folder for a specific csv file `foo.csv`, once the file is located it pulls it to my local and generate a new output format `bar.csv`, the application then will send the new file `bar.csv` back to the FTP folder and erase it from local.

Now I want to introduce a process that will read `bar.csv` and insert it in a database table before sending it FTP server again.

I'm assuming that this could be done using Spring Batch Integration but I could not find how to do it.

Below is my application code for reference and suggestions.

```
public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                            .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv"))
                            .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),//FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
            .enrichHeaders(h ->h.headerExpression("file_originalFile", "new java.io.File('"+ myBranch.getBranchCode() +"/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv')",true))
            .transform(p -> {
                LOG.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());
                return p;
            })

            .log()
            .transform(m -> {
                        this.defaultSessionFactoryLocator.addSessionFactory(myBranch.getBranchCode(),createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch));
                        LOG.info("Adding factory to delegation");
                        return m;
            })

            .publishSubscribeChannel(s ->
                    s.subscribe(f -> f.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest()).handle(jobLaunchingGateway()).channel("nullChannel"))
                    .subscribe(h -> h.handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                                     .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                                     .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                                     .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))))
            /*.handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))*/
            .get();
}

@Bean
public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest(){
    FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(orderJob);
    return fileMessageToJobRequest;
}

@Bean
public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    //simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
    JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);

    return jobLaunchingGateway;
}
```

File message to Job class

```
public class FileMessageToJobRequest {

    private Job job;
    private String fileParameterName;

    public void setFileParameterName(String fileParameterName) {
        this.fileParameterName = fileParameterName;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    @Transformer
    public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder =
                new JobParametersBuilder();

        jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName,
                message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());//message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath()

        return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    }
}
```

Error I'm getting when I'm adding a flow at run time.

```
2019-07-02 12:42:49.292  INFO 7476 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\finalBEY.csv, id=38827020-c9c1-aa35-526c-cc6848ca5e11, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1562060569292}]]
2019-07-02 12:42:49.292  INFO 7476 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=BEY\finalBEY.csv, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv, id=abbe6169-7f46-fcb9-be9e-44533ab05ec8, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1562060569292}]
2019-07-02 12:42:49.295 ERROR 7476 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [jobLaunchingGateway]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=JobLaunchRequest: orderJob, parameters={input.file.name=C:\Java Programs\spring4ftpappftp\BEY\finalBEY.csv}, headers={file_originalFile=BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv, id=f7b2560e-e435-009b-2b8e-27ef168a6767, file_name=finalBEY.csv, file_relativePath=finalBEY.csv, timestamp=1562060569293}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:378)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:372)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler.launch(JobLaunchingMessageHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway.handleRequestMessage(JobLaunchingGateway.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    ... 100 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider to use a `publishSubscribeChannel()` in your `IntegtrationFlow` definition. Place as one subscriber your `.handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter())` (would be better as second). And as the first one it should be something like `.handle(jobLaunchingGateway).channel("nullChannel")`.

You can read about `JobLaunchingGateway` in the Spring Batch [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages).

The point is that you want to send the same message to several places. So, `PublishSubscribeChannel` is the best way to go: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#java-dsl-subflows

I suggest you to have those subscriber exactly in that order since you really want to store into DB before sending to FTP. Without an `executor` the second subscriber will wait until the first finishes its job.

That `.channel("nullChannel")` is necessary there because `JobLaunchingGateway` is really a gateway and it returns a `JobExecution` as a reply. Since you are not interested in that, you just need to ignore. Of course you may have another `handle()` after  that gateway to process this `JobExecution` some way. The point is do not return anything from the fist subscriber as a reply. It is going to brake your main flow somehow.

**UPDATE**

I think `.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())` must go to the first subscriber below just before `jobLaunchingGateway`:

```
 .publishSubscribeChannel(s ->
                s.subscribe(f -> f.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest()).handle(jobLaunchingGateway()).channel("nullChannel"))
                .subscribe(h -> h.handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), ...))
```

The point is that you would like to send the same file to the next `handle()`, but after that transformer upstream it is going to be changed into `JobLaunchRequest`, which is good for `jobLaunchingGateway`, but not is for `Ftp.outboundAdapter()`.

Your exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
```

leads to this piece of code: `Assert.notNull(jobParameters, "The JobParameters must not be null.");`. So, somehow that `jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters()` evaluates to `null`.

I can't help you with so much custom code.

**UPDATE2**

OK. Looks like your problem is in the `JobLaunchingGateway` bean definition. You do there an explicit `new SimpleJobLauncher()` without a `JobRepository` injection.

Looks like there is a `BasicBatchConfigurer` in the `BatchConfigurerConfiguration` of Spring Boot, which can be injected into this `JobLaunchingGateway`. Therefore we will pass a NPE. There are other errors afterward, but that's already a different story...

Comment: Thanks Artem, I'm almost there, I added all the classes needed and methods but getting an error when adding the flow at run time, I have updated my code and pasted the new classes I added, trying to figure out how to solve the error but still not able to do so, can you guide me on this simple one? @Artem Bilan

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. It might not be what you expect, but you need to bear with us to share so much custom code. Would be great if you narrow the problem to some short and specific context. Why do you need to register flows at runtime though? What is wrong having them as beans?

Comment: I removed unnecessary code and left the ones needed, I have a frontend form (Thymeleaf) where the user will enter FTP credentials and create the flows for him, I do not have a preset FTPs in DB to pull out and delegate them...etc, I tried your update and put the `transformer` inside the subscriber but getting the same `null pointer exception` I can see now `Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch)` is working fine as it is sending `bar.csv` to FTP server, the issue I can see it created is on the `success` advice it is not deleting `bar.csv` anymore @Artem Bilan

Comment: Maybe you can't delete it because of that `SimpleJobLauncher`. You might nee to wait until the job is done. Would be great if you can debug your solution and place a break point in the `FileMessageToJobRequest` to figure out what is your `JobLaunchRequest` is on the return...

Comment: After debugging `FileMessageToJobRequest` I can see that the msg passed to the `toRequest()` does not include in it `input.file.name` but the return of the method is a linked hash map of size 1 and it contains `C:\Java Programs\spring4ftpappftp\BEY\finalBEY.csv` so far it should be fine I guess but not sure why it is ending up with null exception, I added a screen shot of what I'm seeing with debug@Artem Bilan

Comment: Hi Artem, can you help further with this issue, I added a screen shot of the debugging and it is showing that the parameter contains the correct folder location...does it throw null exception if the file was deleted from the local folder?I tried this solution and removed the code where it deletes the file from the local but its still giving the null exception,can you please assist with your experience?@Artem Bilan

Comment: Yeah... Unfortunately it is hard from here to say what is wrong and where to go. Is there a chance that you can share with us some simple project we can run on our side and reproduce the issue? Fortunately for you I also use a Windows, so our environments should be similar. Only the problem that I don't have FTP, but I guess we don't need it in your case since we have a problem on the `handle(jobLaunchingGateway())` yet.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have uploaded the project to github and here is the link (https://github.com/EliasKhattar/SpringBatchIntegration) this should send csv file `finalBEY.csv` from folder `BEY` on the classpath to batch and as you know it is giving null pointer, the config file in question is `FTPIntegration` under folder `springframeworkftp.spring4ftpapp.configuration` and `BEY\finalBEY.csv` is also there for the testing, once running it `java.lang.NullPointerException` will show up, please do let me know if still need more info@Artem Bilan

Comment: Can you rework your application somehow without an external data base? I just don't have PostgreSQL... :cry:

Comment: Try please to remove the db setup in 'application.properties' and you can use embedded h2 db and it should work smoothly if you couldn't do it then will upload a new fixed one tomorrow...sorry for the trouble but my laptop is at work and using my tab now to reply...thanks again@Artem Bilan

Comment: See an UPDATE2 in my answer. How that'll help you to proceed a little bit.

Comment: Perfect, adding the `jobRepository` in `JobLaunchingGateway` made it work smooth for the github project, I tried to add it on the actual project but it gave another error, I will raise a new question for that and explain what is happening exactly..thank you again@Artem Bilan